# Additional filter of entity in Spring data based on profile

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a DB table, let's call it USERS. In this table, I have standard fields like `name`, `surname`, `age`, etc.
This table is mapped to the JPA entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    //etc...
}
```

Now I need to have the possibility to filter some of the users based on the environment. The environment can be defined based on the Spring active profile. 
My assumption was to add the new DB column, let's say `boolean filter`, and based on the Spring profile to filter or not the user out.

The question is about the best way of implementation of this functionality so it would be clean and maintainable.
One way is to have two different `@Repository` and based on the profile init the right one. One repository will return all the users but the other one will return only the users with `filter=false`.

What I don't like about this implementation is that there will be a lot of code duplication. For each repository method, I will have to have the same method in the second repository, but with the filtering based on one column. Is there a way do define maybe some kind of `interceptor`` that will do it automatically for each read query on the given DB entity?

Comment: Maybe misunderstood, but I don't believe that additional column would be a good solution though. It will only take more memory from your db and make your data tightly coupled with service environments.

Comment: @Nobody I'd be happy to consider any other solutions. I don't consider my solution as the best one, thus I will be grateful for any other solution that can be provided

Answer (score 1):

Not interceptor, but one can do it using jpa criteria: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

This way you can dynamically configure what you want. Afaik, in runtime it would be a bit slower than plain old solution with several @Repository marked with @ConditionalOnProperty, or other bit of configuration of your choice, however, it meets your requirement of changing behavior without  the need of introducing several repos. What you would want to do is declare Specification /default one and pass it around. This way you could later on also configure your search in runtime too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I don't like about this approach is that in this case, the repository will know about the spring profile and the environment in which it runs. I would not having this dependency in the repository.

Comment: In approach with specification your repository will not know about profile. However,  is it _really_  that bad to have separate solutions for separate problems/environments?

Comment: The specification looks interesting. I should definitely look into it. It is not bad to have a separate solution. What is the main goal that I want to achieve is the possibility inject from the outside of the application what solution has to be used. This is why I think the Spring profile matches it. However I don't want to expose it throught my application, as this is just the configuration and not the bussiness logic